# Routing of test.html file -MVC return 404

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My target is redirect request requsting test.html to test2.html by user agent, Im using MVC so i was following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2013/08/29/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works.aspx) article

So in my /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs is :

```
 routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Test",
        url: "test.html",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Html", page = urlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

and in webconfig i placed following node:

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="test.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

however when i change setting for debugging in IIS and requested localhost:96/test.html the breakpoint in action isnt hit and 404 not found is returned

From article which i linked above i think i made everything also i googled a lot and this should be it but it isnt.. i probably forcing some bug. I will be glad for any suggestons ! If you think that it will be dependent to some versios of SW or OS i can fill them here

Comment: have you created the html action in your homecontroller?

Comment: yes i made it. but even if i wouldnt made it there should be exception and not 404

Comment: I always get the IIS 404 if I don't make my action but I do get an exception if I don't create a view

Comment: Strange but controller and action is there :-/

Comment: you could try moving the route to the top of the config so it is the first rule and see if that changes anything - sometimes other rules might cause errors

Answer (score 0):

On your map route URL, explicitly identify the path of the file:

```
url: "folder1/folder2/{page}.html
```

Then try making this on your controller:

```
 public ActionResult StaticPage()
        {
            var name = new Uri(Request.Url.ToString()).Segments.Last();
            return new FilePathResult(name, "text/html");
        }
```